# Validating a blank field Rails Model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model

This may be somewhat basic but cannot find a definitive answer anywhere. I have set up a contact form within my app and have put in a hidden field that when completed disables the submit button with some Jquery. My attempt at stopping automated spam..

Can I also add some validations in my model?

```
validates :ghost, :presence => false
```

Looking at the docs this is invalid? I want the form to fail if this field is filled in. Not sure how to go about this one

**EDIT**

So I have now read that I could possibly use

```
 validates_exclusion_of :ghost, :on => :create
```

Though this is still failing as i dont think i am passing the correct arguments.

Answer (score 5):

`:presence => false` means that you disable presence validator.

You need to write own absence validation (though in Rails 4.0 such validation exists, `absence: true`).

```
validate :ghost_is_absent

def ghost_is_absent
  errors.add :ghost if ghost.present?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to say , but why are you trying to do things so differently, doing it this way will make things more confusing for any future developer working on this piece of validation.
First thing:
1) You can do the reverse of it , mark it as spam when the field is empty and vice versa and then simply check with the validation validates_presence_of :ghost
2)or if you want to protect spam use capcha (recapcha gem for that)

3) or if you want it do it your way only , then just add a custom validation
Try creating a custom validation.

```
validate :check_for_spam

def check_for_spam
    errors.add_to_base "ghost is present this is a spam" if ghost.present?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if :ghost is blank:

```
  validates :ghost, inclusion: {in: ['']}
```

If you want to check if :ghost is nil, you have to rely to a custom validator.